# Upload app on Dropbox and share it

Tags: support

If I have an Android app, can I upload source code on Dropbox and share it on a post rather than posting the whole code?

Of course, there will be explanation of the problem.

Comment: I don't see a problem with providing off-site links to code **as long as you also include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. The off-site link should be an extra, not necessary to answer the question.

Answer (score 9):

You should post the [minimal amount of pertinent code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that helps explain your problem in the question and avoid linking to something downloadable.

Most people will be very wary of downloading anything to their local machine. They don't know where it originates from, what it might contain, or might not have the proper tools or software to do anything useful with it.

Additionally, if you remove the link at any point, your question becomes 100% useless without the code in the question.